# Simplify the CFG Swift Enum Rawvalue

Tags: swift, enums, llvm

I am receiving the following error when I Archive or Profile in Xcode. The odd thing is that this error does not occur when Building, Analyzing or Testing.

I receive the following error:

`Running pass 'Simplify the CFG' on function '@_TFO9HVAC_Plus10Paragrafeng5titleSS'`

I have found out that the problem is in the following lines of code:

```
var title: String {
    return rawValue
}
```

As you can see, title is a property of an enum. The error occurs in Xcode 6.3

This is the rest of my code:

```
enum Paragrafen: String, Enumeratable, Printable {
    case Transmissieverlies = "52.1 Bepalen transmissieverlies per meter geïsoleerde buis"
    case BreedteRechthoekigKanaal = "61.1 Bepalen breedte rechthoekig kanaal"
    case SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal = "61.2 Bepalen snelheid rechthoekig kanaal"
    case WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal = "61.3 Bepalen weerstand rechthoekig kanaal"
    case SnelheidRondKanaal = "61.4 Bepalen snelheid rond kanaal"
    case WeerstandRondKanaal = "61.5 Bepalen weerstand rond kanaal"
    case VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik = "61.6 Bepalen ventilator vermogen en elektra verbruik"

    var unlocked: Bool {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(self.searchTitle)
        }
        set {
            let def = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            def.setBool(newValue, forKey: self.searchTitle)
            def.synchronize()
        }
    }

    var searchTitle: String {
        switch self {
        case .Transmissieverlies:
            return "52_transmissieverlies"
        case .BreedteRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "61_breedte"
        case .SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "61_snelheid_recht"
        case .WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "61_weerstand_recht"
        case .SnelheidRondKanaal:
            return "61_snelheid_rond"
        case .WeerstandRondKanaal:
            return "61_weerstand_rond"
        case .VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik:
            return "61_ventilator_vermogen_verbruik"
        }
    }

    static var allValues: [Enumeratable] { return [Paragrafen.Transmissieverlies, Paragrafen.BreedteRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.SnelheidRondKanaal, Paragrafen.WeerstandRondKanaal, Paragrafen.VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik] }


    static func paragrafenForHoofdstuk(hoofdstuk: Hoofdstukken) -> [Paragrafen] {
        switch hoofdstuk{
        case .Tapwaterinstallaties:
            return [Paragrafen.Transmissieverlies]
        case .Luchtbehandelingsinstallaties:
            return [Paragrafen.BreedteRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.SnelheidRondKanaal, Paragrafen.WeerstandRondKanaal, Paragrafen.VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik]
        }
    }

    var calculation: Calculations {
        switch self {
        case .Transmissieverlies:
            return Calculations.Transmissieverlies
        case .BreedteRechthoekigKanaal:
            return Calculations.BreedteRechthoekigKanaal
        case .SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal:
            return Calculations.SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal
        case .WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal:
            return Calculations.WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal
        case .SnelheidRondKanaal:
            return Calculations.SnelheidRondKanaal
        case .WeerstandRondKanaal:
            return Calculations.WeerstandRondKanaal
        case .VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik:
            return Calculations.VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik
        }
    }

    var title: String {
        return rawValue as String
    }

    var description: String {
        return title
    }

    var hoofdstuk: Hoofdstukken {
        switch self {
        case .Transmissieverlies:
            return Hoofdstukken.Tapwaterinstallaties
        case .BreedteRechthoekigKanaal, .SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal, .WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal, .SnelheidRondKanaal, .WeerstandRondKanaal, .VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik:
            return Hoofdstukken.Luchtbehandelingsinstallaties
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the rest of the enum so I can see if I can reproduce the error?

Comment: yes, but some enum variables are depending on other enums

Comment: I can reproduce the error, but it happens when there are more than 4 `case` statements.

Comment: Do you know a fix? except for deleting several cases.

Comment: Not yet, but I've narrowed it down a bit more - if you edit your Scheme and under Profile, change Build Configuration to `Debug` you no longer get the error.

Comment: I need to archive the app....

Comment: By default, Archive uses the `Release` build configuration too.

Comment: You **SHOULD** archive using release settings. Debug settings turn off code optimization (especially bad for Swift - in the current version unoptimized code is quite slow) and also leaves symbols in the code, which is bad because it makes your code substantially easier to reverse-engineer.

Comment: This sounds like an Xcode 6.3 compiler bug to me. I'd suggest finding a simpler case (like @ABakerSmith says he has) and using that to file sample code that produces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something in my project, and now it builds perfectly fine. This is what I did (I don't know what actually solved my problem, whether it is just one of below noted measures or a combination of them):

- I removed references to rawValue
- I reduced the memory size of rawValue (changing "61.1 ...." to "61.1"
- I added a switch in title to make sure I get the normal values

This is my new code (still a bit messy though):

```
enum Paragrafen: String, Enumeratable, Printable {
    case Transmissieverlies = "52.1"// = "52.1 Bepalen transmissieverlies per meter geïsoleerde buis"
    case BreedteRechthoekigKanaal = "61.1"// Bepalen breedte rechthoekig kanaal"
    case SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal = "61.2"// Bepalen snelheid rechthoekig kanaal"
    case WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal = "61.3"// Bepalen weerstand rechthoekig kanaal"
    case SnelheidRondKanaal = "61.4"// Bepalen snelheid rond kanaal"
    case WeerstandRondKanaal = "61.5"// Bepalen weerstand rond kanaal"
    case VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik = "61.6"// Bepalen ventilator vermogen en elektra verbruik"

    var unlocked: Bool {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(self.searchTitle)
        }
        set {
            let def = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            def.setBool(newValue, forKey: self.searchTitle)
            def.synchronize()
        }
    }

    var searchTitle: String {
        switch self {
        case .Transmissieverlies:
            return "52_transmissieverlies"
        case .BreedteRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "61_breedte"
        case .SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "61_snelheid_recht"
        case .WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "61_weerstand_recht"
        case .SnelheidRondKanaal:
            return "61_snelheid_rond"
        case .WeerstandRondKanaal:
            return "61_weerstand_rond"
        case .VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik:
            return "61_ventilator_vermogen_verbruik"
        }
    }

    static var allValues: [Enumeratable] { return [Paragrafen.Transmissieverlies, Paragrafen.BreedteRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.SnelheidRondKanaal, Paragrafen.WeerstandRondKanaal, Paragrafen.VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik] }


    static func paragrafenForHoofdstuk(hoofdstuk: Hoofdstukken) -> [Paragrafen] {
        switch hoofdstuk{
        case .Tapwaterinstallaties:
            return [Paragrafen.Transmissieverlies]
        case .Luchtbehandelingsinstallaties:
            return [Paragrafen.BreedteRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal, Paragrafen.SnelheidRondKanaal, Paragrafen.WeerstandRondKanaal, Paragrafen.VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik]
        }
    }

    var calculation: Calculations {
        switch self {
        case .Transmissieverlies:
            return Calculations.Transmissieverlies
        case .BreedteRechthoekigKanaal:
            return Calculations.BreedteRechthoekigKanaal
        case .SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal:
            return Calculations.SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal
        case .WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal:
            return Calculations.WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal
        case .SnelheidRondKanaal:
            return Calculations.SnelheidRondKanaal
        case .WeerstandRondKanaal:
            return Calculations.WeerstandRondKanaal
        case .VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik:
            return Calculations.VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik
        }
    }

    var paragraphTitle: String {
        switch self {
        /*case Paragrafen.Transmissieverlies:
            return "52.1 Bepalen transmissieverlies per meter geïsoleerde buis"
        case Paragrafen.BreedteRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "61.1 Bepalen breedte rechthoekig kanaal"
        case Paragrafen.SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "61.2 Bepalen snelheid rechthoekig kanaal"
        case Paragrafen.WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "61.3 Bepalen weerstand rechthoekig kanaal"
        case Paragrafen.SnelheidRondKanaal:
            return "61.4 Bepalen snelheid rond kanaal"
        case Paragrafen.WeerstandRondKanaal:
            return "61.5 Bepalen weerstand rond kanaal"
        case Paragrafen.VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik:
            return "61.6 Bepalen ventilator vermogen en elektra verbruik"*/
        case .Transmissieverlies:
            return "Transmissieverlies"
        case .BreedteRechthoekigKanaal:
            return "Bepalen breedte rechthoekig kanaal"
        default:
            return ""
        }
    }

    var description: String {
        return paragraphTitle
    }

    var hoofdstuk: Hoofdstukken {
        switch self {
        case .Transmissieverlies:
            return Hoofdstukken.Tapwaterinstallaties
        case .BreedteRechthoekigKanaal, .SnelheidRechthoekigKanaal, .WeerstandRechthoekigKanaal, .SnelheidRondKanaal, .WeerstandRondKanaal, .VentilatorVermogenEnElektraVerbruik:
            return Hoofdstukken.Luchtbehandelingsinstallaties
        }
    }
}
```